# Batch file executed from context menu - different behaviour between 'open' and 'open with'

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an issue where depending whether created batch file (run on the file via context menu - right click) results in different outcome.

If the batch file is selected to be a default program (not desired setup) to open the file it works fine. I.e. right-click>'open' or double-click

If the batch file is only selectable from 'open with' menu but default program is different (desired setup) the batch file starts but no outcome is produced

The batch file is very simple, executes a program that requires two arguments - input file and destination folder:

```
@echo off
"PCAP Generator.exe" %~dpnx1 %cd%
DEL *.log /q
```

Could you kindly help to explain why the behaviour differs?
Could you kindly help to correct the batch file for it to operate correctly in case batch file is selectable by right-click > 'open with' menu and is not a default program to open the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change in first line `@echo off` to `@echo on` and add one more line at bottom with command `pause`. Then you can see what the batch file does. BTW: `%~f1` is short for `%~dpnx1`. And most likely you need to enclose both parameters in double quotes as `~` removes the double quotes, but both parameters can contain 1 or more spaces or other characters requiring double quotes. So use `"PCAP Generator.exe" "%~f1" "%cd%"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely even better would be:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1" == "" (
    "PCAP Generator.exe" "%~f1" "%~dp1"
    del /Q "%~dp1*.log" 2>nul
)
```

A simple test is made if batch file is called without a parameter.

`%~dp1` references drive letter and path of first parameter passed to this batch file. This string ends with a backslash.

The deletion of the log files is done in quiet mode with suppressing the error message in case of no LOG file in directory.

For details on used commands, open a command prompt window and execute there:

- `call /?` ... output help explains `%~dp1` and `%~f1`.
- `del /?` ... output help explains option `/Q`.

In general running a command or a console application with parameter `/?` in command prompt window results in getting help for this command or console application output in 1 or more window pages.

There is also the command `help` listing Windows standard commands if executed without any parameter while running `help` with name of a command like `help call` results in same help output as when running `call /?`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was:

If 'open with' is used the %cd% location is set to C:\Windows\system32

```
C:\Windows\system32>ECHO cd "C:\Windows\system32"
```

If script is set to be default and run via 'open' then %cd% location is set correctly to the folder where the input file is located.

```
C:_LOGS>ECHO cd "C:_LOGS"
```

The solution to avoid this problem is:

```
@echo off
"PCAP Generator.exe" "%~f1" C:%~p1
del C:%~p1*.log
```

Thank you very much for your help